# intersection oberserver used with a loop through all the elements ends in error

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show some cards on scroll and for that purpose I chose to use an intersection observer.
But I ended up with: 
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'IntersectionObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'. 
Here is a sample code of what I am trying to do =>

HTML:

```
<div class="card">demo</div>
<div class="card">demo</div>
<div class="card">demo</div>
<div class="card">demo</div>
```

JS:

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

const options = {
    root: null,
    threshold: 0.2
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            entry.target.classList.add("appear-on-scroll");
            observer.unobserve(entry.target);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    });
}, options);
observer.observe(cards);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to loop through the array that consists of nodes twice like:

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

const options = {
    root: null,
    threshold: 0.2
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            entry.target.classList.add("appear-on-scroll");
            observer.unobserve(entry.target);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    });
}, options);

// second loop through
cards.forEach(card => observer.observe(card));
```